# Safety of if statement and if-else statement

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-construction

My question may be weird or even unnecessary. Will it do any harm to always satisfy the condition in *if* statement and omit *else* like **snippet 1**?

```
if (condition 1) {

    // code here

    if (condition 2) {

        // code here

    }
}
```

Or, is **snippet 2** better?

```
if (condition 1) {

    // code here

    if (!condition 2) {
        return;
    }

    else {

        // code here

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this. Are you asking if it's OK to omit the else branch of an if statement?

Comment: use `else` if you need it

Comment: @Wang Well then -- it's OK. It's optional. Read the relevant part in the C++ standard.

Comment: Don't use `if` its evil

Comment: @doctorlove I hope that was sarcastic!?

Comment: The two code examples don't necessarily do the same thing. The second has a return, the first does not.

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry world I have some evil code at work I must post on the dailywtf. I was thinking about this: http://www.antiifcampaign.com/

Comment: @doctorlove Ah, thanks. That's interesting. Sounds like trolling, though. :P

Comment: @H2CO3 I'll get my goat ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some guidelines (in the automotive industry, for example) specify that the else statement must be included, even if it's empty. In that case, you can make a comment inside the else statement specifying that you actually don't want to do anything inside it.

One advantage that I can think of is this. If you have:

```
if (condition)
    doSomething();
doSomethingElse();
```

In this scenario, the if case will execute doSomething() and the else case will execute doSomethingElse(). If you now modify your code like this:

```
if (condition)
    doSomething();
doSomethingElse();
doAnother();
```

what do you think will happen? The else case will execute only doSomethingElse(). The doAnother() will execute in both cases (if and else). But is this really what you want? Maybe it is, maybe it isn't. Maybe you wanted something like:

```
if (condition) 
{
    doSomething();
}
else
{
    doSomethingElse();
    doAnother();
}
```

In this situation, doAnother() clearly belongs to the else case.

So, specify the else explicitly when you have code that changes frequently or it's modified by more than one developer. It really makes things clearer and avoids mistakes/bugs in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run some code only if the condition isn't true you have tou add else or else if. 
Below an exemple :

```
if (condition) {
     a=5;
}
else {
     a=8;
}
```

if condition is true -> a=5, if not, a=8.

```
if (condition) {
     a=5;
}
a=8;
```

a=8 in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Well... First of. If you ALWAYS satisfy the if statement you don't need an if statement at all. Regarding having an if statement that can actually "fail" you don't need an else statement unless there is something specific that should happen if the statement you are checking against is false.

So in short... You don't have to put it in "just because".

Answer (score 0):

There are two rules (which are (how can it be any different) in conflict) when it comes to readability of source code:

- Test for the condition that's in the one true path, handle the other case using `else` (if it needs to be handled at all).
- Test for positive conditions, not for negations.

Answer (score 0):

The one advantage I can see for always including an `else`-statement is guarding against silly mistakes like

```
if (ptr != 0);
    ptr = ptr->next;
```

Given that you can't have something like an `else`-branch for `while`- or `for`-loops it is an incomplete approach, though.